# How to move to another tab without clicking the tab on Android Studio?

Tags: android, tabs

My main activity pretty much sets up the tabs and displays the content inside the ViewPager. I am able to navigate to another tab by clicking the tabs.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private SectionsPageAdapter pageAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager((mViewPager));


    }

    // Add fragments to SectionsPageAdapter and give titles
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new ProfileTab(), "Profile");
        adapter.addFragment(new GithubTab(), "Github Repos");
        adapter.addFragment(new FollowerTab(), "Followers");
        adapter.addFragment(new FollowingTab(), "Followings");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}
```

However, when I try to navigate to another tab by clicking on a TextView from one of the pages, it gives me an error. What I've tried so far is,

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_tab, container, false);

        ... Code Hidden ...
        // numRepos is the TextView that I have

        numRepos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "num repos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
            }
        });


        return view;
```

And I actually knew this wouldn't work because the viewPager in this page is not same as the ViewPager in the MainActivity.java. How can I navigate to another tab by clicking the numRepos TextView?

Comment: put your error logcat

Comment: textview is inside one of the fragement? means in any tab's fragment?

Comment: @VishvaDave Just one of the fragments. I am basically trying to move to the "GithubTab" fragment by clicking the "numRepos" TextView on the "ProfileTab"

Comment: then you need to findviewbyid of viewpager in fragment by getActivity().findViewById..then set current item will work

Comment: did you tried this  viewPager.setCurrentItem(2, true);

Comment: @VishvaDave Do you mean, viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(); This? But I don't actually have a viewPager in this fragment.

Comment: @user6792790 that's why you need getActivity. for find view by id because it is in the activity and you want to access it in its fragment

Comment: ActionBar actionBar = (ActionBar)getActivity().getActionBar();
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(1);

Comment: @user6792790 just try this once. will solve your issue

Comment: @VishvaDave Could you please provide the code snippet? I don't quite understand how I have to put it..

Comment: @user6792790 see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this in your fragment** :

```
ViewPager mviewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
```

this id will be your viewpager id which is given in activity layout.

then just use this. `mviewPager.setCurrentItem(2);`

Comment: The thing is, I don't have a thing with id = viewpager in my fragment. The viewpager is only inside the MainActivity

Comment: yes it is in the activity. but fragments can use any components of their activity which contains them. you only need to getactivity(). for finding any component of activity

Comment: you just copy paste this lines and use your view pager id which is in activity layout. and check it. if not works then please ask

Answer (score 1):

Create **STATIC** method in **`MainActivity`** section.

```
public static ViewPager mViewPager; //GLOBAL
public static SectionsPageAdapter pageAdapter; //GLOBAL

public static void _openITEM() // Create this static method
{
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
}
```

**Then**

```
numRepos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               _openITEM();
            }
        });
```

Comment: did you mean mViewPager in the _openITEM ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. This works too, but I selected another answer. But I really appreciate it!

Comment: @user6792790 Move ahead!

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in the `onClick` method:

```
TabActivity tabs = (TabActivity) getParent();
tabs.getTabHost().setCurrentTab(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add the viewPager findViewById Like this maybe help

```
 viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity.findViewById(R.id.container);
 numRepos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "num repos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create this method in your `MainActivity` -

```
public void navigateToPage(int i) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
    }
```

Then call this method like this from any of your fragments -

```
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).navigateToPage(2);
```